# What average block time does the Etheruem network try to achieve?

Tags: blockchain

> What average block time does the Etheruem network try to achieve?

The average block time has varied from ~30 seconds to ~14 seconds according to https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime.

Does the yellowpaper define a "canonical" average block time that the network try to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate question -
 https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58/why-is-the-average-block-time-17-seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the average block time and other neat stats [here](https://ethstats.net/).

I understand the [initial target](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/11/toward-a-12-second-block-time/) was 12 seconds but at the time of writing, the average block time is 15s, which I understand is the desired target.

Before the metropolis release block times increased significantly but this was expected (see [Ice Age](https://steemit.com/ethereum/@joshbreslauer/ethereum-is-entering-the-ice-age)).